# adding jsf-facelets.jar in JSF2 project

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

Im new in JSF 2 and I wan to konw if I have to add the  jsf-facelets.jar to my project lib or it's included in the JSF 2 jars.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add Facelets 1.x libraries to a JSF 2.x project. It would only collide. Leave them away. It's already included in JSF 2.x libraries.